# How to use the third variable in range?

Tags: jinja2, kubernetes-helm

There are variables in `values.yaml` of my Helm Chart:

```yaml
stand: dev-gfdz-loader
ingress1:
  entrypoints: pdu
```

In Helm Chart I have:

```yaml
      {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.secretObjects }}
      - secretKey: {{ $key | quote}}
        objectName: {{ $value | quote }}
        secretPath: "pdu/data/dev-gfdz-loader"
      {{- end }}
```

This example is working.

In the line `"pdu/data/dev-gfdz-loader"` I need:
replace `pdu` with `ingress1.entrypoints` and
replace `dev-gfdz-loader` with `stand`

Finally, if I do this:

```yaml
      {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.secretObjects }}
      - secretKey: {{ $key | quote}}
        objectName: {{ $value | quote }}
        secretPath: "{{ .Values.ingress1.entrypoints }}/data/{{ .Values.stand }}"
      {{- end }}
```

Then I get an error:

```
 Error: template: app/charts/rr/templates/secretproviderclass.yaml:23:31: executing "app/charts/rr/templates/secretproviderclass.yaml" at <.Values.ingress1.entrypoints>: can't evaluate field Values in type interface {} Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
      {{- $entrypoints := .Values.ingress1.entrypoints -}}
      {{- $stand := .Values.stand -}}
      {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.secretObjects }}
      - secretKey: "{{ $key }}"
        objectName: "{{ $value }}"
        secretPath: "{{ $entrypoints }}/data/{{ $stand }}"
      {{- end }}
```